# How do I generate a self-signed certificate using PHP and OpenSSL

Tags: php, openssl, certificate

I'm trying to make a site that generates a self signed certificate using PHP and openSSL. I'm pretty sure it's some sort of syntax error but I cannot seem to find it.

I've tried the command in the linux terminal and it seems to work, but only in the PHP file, it doesn't work.

This is work.php, it is mainly the function:

```
<?php

function terminal($command)
{
        //system
        if(function_exists('system'))
        {
                ob_start();
                system($command , $return_var);
                $output = ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean();
        }
        //passthru
        else if(function_exists('passthru'))
        {
                ob_start();
                passthru($command , $return_var);
                $output = ob_get_contents();
                ob_end_clean();
        }

        //exec
        else if(function_exists('exec'))
        {
                exec($command , $output , $return_var);
                $output = implode(n , $output);
        }

        //shell_exec
        else if(function_exists('shell_exec'))
        {
                $output = shell_exec($command) ;
        }

        else
        {
                $output = 'Command execution not possible on this system';
                $return_var = 1;
        }

        return array('output' => $output , 'status' => $return_var);
}

?>
```

And this is index.php which is the main file

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" placeholder="domain" name="name"></input>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"></input>
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   $name = $_POST["name"];
   run();
}

function run() {
require "work.php";
$status = 0;
$name = $_POST["name"];


$command1 = "openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout " . $name . ".key -out " . $name . ".pem -days 3650 -subj '/CN=" . $name . "'";
$o = terminal($command1);

echo $o['output'];
echo "<br><br>";
echo "Your certificate >> <a href='" . $name . ".pem'>DOWNLOAD</a>";
echo "<br>";
echo "Your private key >> <a href='" . $name . ".key'>DOWNLOAD</a>";

}

?>
```

Comment: why not use some of the native openssl functions available within PHP rather than trying to run a php script on the commandline via PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as example how one might potentially generate certificates using native php functions rather than executing a string command

```
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    $result=false;



    /* 
        configure as appropriate - the root directory
        for all web data
    */
    $rootdir='c:\wwwroot';
    /*
        an aliased directory within web root - select
        an appropriate path
    */
    $certdir=$rootdir . '\content\stack';
    /* 
        to aid correct display of hyperlinks for my environment
        which uses aliases and symbolic links so probably not
        required otherwise
    */
    $displaypath=dirname( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );






    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['name'] ) ){


        $name=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'name', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );


        if( $name ){



            function create( $rootdir='c:/wwwroot', $certdir=false, $certname='certificate', $dn=array(), $passphrase=null, $createpem=true, $overwrite=true ){
                if( !empty( $certdir ) && !empty( $certname ) && !empty( $dn ) ){

                    $out = new stdClass;
                    $days = 3650;

                    /* !!! configuration and location of your own openssl.conf file is important !!! */
                    putenv( sprintf( 'OPENSSL_CONF=%s/openssl.cnf', $rootdir ) );

                    $config=array(
                        'config'            =>  getenv('OPENSSL_CONF'),
                        'digest_alg'        =>  'AES-128-CBC',
                        'private_key_bits'  =>  4096,
                        'private_key_type'  =>  OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
                        'encrypt_key'       =>  false
                    );

                    /*
                        Primary configuration is overwritten at runtime
                        by including parameters in the "$dn" argument
                    */
                    $dn=array_merge( array(
                        "countryName"               => "UK",
                        "stateOrProvinceName"       => "Strathclyde",
                        "localityName"              => "Scotland",
                        "organizationName"          => "bonny-scotland.org",
                        "organizationalUnitName"    => "Bonny Scotland",
                        "commonName"                => $certname,
                        "emailAddress"              => "webmaster@bonny-scotland.org"
                    ), $dn );

                    $privkey = openssl_pkey_new( $config );
                    $csr = openssl_csr_new( $dn, $privkey, $config );
                    $cert = openssl_csr_sign( $csr, null, $privkey, $days, $config, 0 );

                    openssl_x509_export( $cert, $out->pub );
                    openssl_pkey_export( $privkey, $out->priv, $passphrase );
                    openssl_csr_export( $csr, $out->csr );



                    # Create the base private & public directories if they do not exist
                    $privdir = $certdir . sprintf('\\certificates\\%s\\private\\',$certname );
                    $pubdir  = $certdir . sprintf('\\certificates\\%s\\public\\',$certname );

                    @mkdir( $privdir, 0777, true );
                    @mkdir( $pubdir, 0777, true );


                    $pkpath=$privdir . $certname . '.key';
                    $cert=$pubdir . $certname . '.crt';
                    $csr=$privdir . $certname . '.csr';
                    $pem=$pubdir . $certname . '.pem';


                    if( !file_exists( $pkpath ) or ( $overwrite==true && file_exists( $pkpath ) ) ) {

                        openssl_pkey_export_to_file( $privkey, $pkpath, $passphrase, $config );

                        file_put_contents( $cert, $out->pub, FILE_TEXT );
                        file_put_contents( $csr, $out->csr, FILE_TEXT );

                        if( $createpem ){
                            unset( $out->csr );
                            file_put_contents( $pem, implode( '', get_object_vars( $out ) ) );
                        }
                    }
                    openssl_pkey_free( $privkey );
                    clearstatcache();

                    /* return useful stuff for display porpoises */
                    return (object)array(
                        'public'        =>  str_replace( $certdir, '', $pubdir ),
                        'private'       =>  str_replace( $certdir, '', $privdir ),
                        'pubsize'       =>  filesize( $pem ),
                        'privsize'      =>  filesize( $pkpath ),
                        'pkpath'        =>  $pkpath,
                        'cert'          =>  $cert,
                        'csr'           =>  $csr,
                        'pem'           =>  $pem,
                        'certificate'   =>  $certname
                    );
                }
                return false;
            }



            /* configure the DN array */
            $dn=array(
                'countryName'               =>  'GB',
                'localityName'              =>  'England',
                'stateOrProvinceName'       =>  'London',
                'organizationName'          =>  $name,
                'organizationalUnitName'    =>  'Squirrel Juggling Services',
                'emailAddress'              =>  sprintf( 'admin-contact@%s', $name )
            );
            $result=create( $rootdir, $certdir, $name, $dn );
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Generate Certificates</title>
        <style>
            body,body *{box-sizing:border-box;font-family:calibri,verdana,arial;}
            body{ background:white; width:100%; height:100vh;margin:0;display:flex;flex-direction:column; align-content:center; justify-content:center; align-items:center;}
            form{ border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25); border-radius:1rem; background:whitesmoke; padding:1rem;width:30%; height:auto; min-height:250px; display:flex; flex-direction:column; align-content:center; justify-content:center; align-items:center; }
            form *{align-self:stretch;flex:1;margin:0.5rem;}
            [type='text']{text-align:center;}
            h1{font-size:1.45rem;text-align:center}
            h2{font-size:1.15rem;text-align:center}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <h1>Generate Self-Signed SSL Certificate</h1>
            <input type='text' name='name' placeholder='domain' />
            <input type='submit' />
        </form>
        <?php
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && is_object( $result ) ){
                printf(
                    '
                    <h2>Certificate for "%s" generated successfully!</h2>
                    <a href="%s" target="_blank">Download Public Certificate ( %s Kb )</a>
                    <a href="%s" target="_blank">Download Private Key ( %s Kb )</a>',

                    $result->certificate,
                    sprintf( '%s%s%s.pem', $displaypath, $result->public, $result->certificate ),
                    round( ( $result->pubsize / 1024 ), 2 ),
                    sprintf( '%s%s%s.key', $displaypath, $result->private, $result->certificate ),
                    round( ( $result->privsize / 1024 ), 2 )
                );
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I seem to be getting these errors on your php code, the site is live on https://theflyingrat.com/test/ssc/test.php         please review these errors as I do not know what's wrong with it. Thanks, Rat

Comment: looks like they all originate with the failure to create the folders - so check / modify the folder permissions for the chosen certificate directory

Comment: I’ve tried it multiple times using chown and chmod but they all seem to not work... i think I’ve implemented the code incorrectly, how would I do this? Make a seperate php file and it will work or do I still need other documents/folders to be created for this to work?

Comment: can you create a pastebin of how you implemented this and share the link so I can have a look when I get back from work?

Comment: Ignore this now, your code is better but I found a way to make it work using different code. Thanks, although permissions still don't work?

Comment: Is it necessary to set the environment variable `OPENSSL_CONF`, when you're providing it in the config parameter to `openssl_pkey_new` and the others anyway?

Comment: @SteenSchütt - TBH this was a long while ago but I believe I **did** manually create the environment variable ( on a Windoze system using `set` or `setx` I think ) to point to the `openssl.cnf` file within the OPENSSL installation directory ( in my case within a sub-directory of the apache dir ).... afaik this env var was not created automatically during install but could be wrong. The `create` function however overrides that env var at runtime with a different config file

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius That's what I thought, but I know OpenSSL is very particular about environment and that config specifically, so I just wanted to ask. It seems to work without that environment variable specified, but it might just be because I'm on Linux and it knows to look in `/etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf`.